# Installing drivers for "BT-930 BusLogic flashpoint LT", Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, iscsi

I'm trying to install the driver for a SCSI controller card: BT-930 BusLogic flashpoint LT.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with kernel 3.2.0-54-generic.

I have (I think) the tarball I require and is sitting on the desktop: BusLogic-2.0.15.tar.gz and I have already unzipped it and it contains 9 files, 2 of which are .c files and one .h file, as well as various readme and release notes documents.

These are the install instructions I have, but I think they were written for another and/or earlier version of Linux.

```
  588 This distribution was prepared for Linux kernel version 2.0.35, but should be
  589 compatible with 2.0.4 or any later 2.0 series kernel.
  590 
  591 To install the new BusLogic SCSI driver, you may use the following commands,
  592 replacing "/usr/src" with wherever you keep your Linux kernel source tree:
  593 
  594   cd /usr/src
  595   tar -xvzf BusLogic-2.0.15.tar.gz
  596   mv README.* LICENSE.* BusLogic.[ch] FlashPoint.c linux/drivers/scsi
  597   patch -p0 < BusLogic.patch (only for 2.0.33 and below)
  598   cd linux
  599   make config
  600   make depend
  601   make zImage
  602 
  603 Then install "arch/i386/boot/zImage" as your standard kernel, run lilo if
  604 appropriate, and reboot.
```

As a Linux newbie,  most of these lines mean absolutely NOTHING to me, but I've typed them into Terminal, copied and pasted them even, but all to no avail.

Please can someone write me a new set of instructions for my version of Ubuntu that will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The driver sources you have downloaded are **very** old and won't compile for your current Linux Kernel you are running. The source mentions `2.0 series Linux kernel`, these were modern about 10 - 15 years ago.

I don't think it is possible to get this controller up and running with Ubuntu. Google gave me this: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1819571/linux-buslogic-930-flashpoint-scsi-card.html

**Edit** Summarizing from the other "answers".

This seems to be the SCSI-Controler originally sold with the Iomega JAZ-Drive. So I guess what you are really after is trying to make this old hardware work again.

If this was my own JAZ drive I'd try to make it run with another more recent SCSI-Controller.

But seeing you need some serious hand-holding doing this I **strongly** suggest to go to your next local [Linux User Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_user_group) if you bring them your equipment and ask nicely they **will** give it a whirl and try their best to make it work...

I can tell from experience. I run my own LUG where I live ;-)

Also, please don't get mad when(or if) the mods are going to delete your other "answers" it's the way askubuntu.com works.